# ATM daily Cash forecasting

Tags: time-series

I want to do forecasting for ATM on daily transcation data.

I have data set for sep 2013 to feb 2014 and i want to validate it for march 2014.

so for this i had using forecast package in R and fit model ARIMA using ARIMA() function. 
I have data with trans_date ,transaction_amount, weekdays and holiday_flag.

I fitted ARIMA model with regressor variable weekdays but in final output my forecast value not matching with actual value for march month. so please help me on this. I share with you data set which i used in my forecasting. In Sheet one there is train data and in sheet two there is validate data.

In this link R code is there which i used...
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mPo0D-iTK5d_b0W5gG2lBmMA95__eG825fFo2yrSyIg/edit

In this link dataset is there...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LJhxzfpMkeCwLf129D9-q5ZkGhISqrDQWCw30UE9TE/pubhtml

help on this really very appreciated....

Comment: You have some days in the dataset that have no values, e.g. Oct-30 - Nov-2. Bank panic? :)
http://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/0baf81ba

Comment: yes i was ignor that date beacause there is zero transaction amount

Comment: how would be calculated those forecast value

Comment: Zero is a valid number. It could be a scheduled repair or bank office closing date. This type of exceptions can impact the quality of forecasting to a great extent. I used automated holt-winters. I let the system crunch numbers and identify HW parameters that best fit test data. For your data it was Alpha=0.2, Beta=0.3, Gamma=0.1. Period = 4 weeks. Data was averaged over 2 days to smooth out spikes.

Comment: did you verify your forecast value with march data which is present in sheet 2.  Can you shared your code for my reference

Comment: how would you capture the seasonality? seasonality is present in weekdays.

Comment: Season is Gamma = 0.1. March data is graphed in silver color on the referenced time chart. I didn't write any code, it was produced by a machine. The machine recomputes the most fitting forecast parameters on new inputs.

Comment: Thanks Sergie for your responce, But i want to do this in R.                   Can any body suggest the another way to do in R

Comment: Sure, that's why I didn't post my response as an answer. Code is definitely better for learning things.

Comment: I am expecting the above question's answer from sir RandomHyndman

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to use the weekdays or weekend dummies if you use a seasonal Arima. You also need to treat the zero value as NA because otherwise it would be a non repetitive outlyier. The question is if you use a stationary or non-stationary model. Cash outlays sometimes are best treated as log, so I put a lambda = 0 for Box - Cox transformation. I enclosed code for both stationary and non-stationary model.

```
library(forecast)
#I put an NA in 9/1/2014
amount <- ts(cash$Amount,start = 1, frequency = 7)
amount <- na.interp(amount, lambda = 0)
fitar <- auto.arima(amount,  xreg = cash$Holydays, lambda = 0 , stepwise = FALSE)
fcstar <- forecast(fitar, h=30, xreg = rep(0,30))
plot(fcstar)
fitar1 <- auto.arima(amount, D=1, xreg = cash$Holydays, lambda = 0 , stepwise = FALSE)
fcstar1 <- forecast(fitar1, h=30, xreg = rep(0,30))
plot(fcstar1)
```

Comment: Thanks Acoustesh for your response, but from this method still seasonality not capture very well. if we validate forecast value with actual data its not match ,variation is there between these value.

Answer (score 0):

The data are collected daily, which would suggest a frequency of 365. However, what evidence do you have for "seasonality" in the data? I don't see any when I plot them.

```
library(forecast)
# data through Feb
datFit <- read.csv("atm_fit.csv")
# convert 0 to NA
datFit$tot_amount[datFit$tot_amount==0] <- NA
nFit <- length(datFit$tot_amount)
beginDay <- (as.Date("2013-09-01") - as.Date("2013-01-01"))
t1 <- ts(datFit$tot_amount, start=c(2013,beginDay), freq=365)
plot.ts(t1)
```

[image: Time series plot]

The other issue is that your values are all greater than zero, so perhaps a log-transformation would be more appropriate (or use a non-Gaussian time series model). Anyway, ignoring that for now let's fit an ARIMA model.

```
tsMod <- auto.arima(t1, xreg=datFit$Holiday_flag)
summary(tsMod)

Series: tt 
ARIMA(3,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2     ar3  intercept  datFit$Holiday_flag
      0.2669  0.1611  0.1102  162648.08            -11568.59
s.e.  0.0757  0.0787  0.0772   11232.19             23829.38

sigma^2 estimated as 4.711e+09:  log likelihood=-2159.72
AIC=4331.44   AICc=4331.95   BIC=4350.36

Training set error measures:
                        ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set -0.0005199295 0.5135824 0.3887894 -0.2049583 3.350222 0.8049315 0.005689687
```

So, it looks like an ARMAX(3,0,0) model is the "best". Now let forecast the March values and examine them.

```
# get March data
datFore <- read.csv("atm_fore.csv")
nFore <- length(datFore$tot_amount)
# forecast March values
ff <- forecast(tsMod, nFore, xreg=rep(0,nFore))
# plot all data together
tf <- ts(c(datFit$tot_amount,datFore$tot_amount), start=c(2013,beginDay), freq=365)
plot.ts(tf)
# fitted values
points(ff$fitted, pch=16, col="blue")
# forecasts
points(ff$mean, pch=16, col="red")
```

[image: data and fits]

So, indeed you have a pretty lousy forecast model that basically reverts to the mean. There is no seasonality in the data, so you should not expect anything from the model either.